# Using `split` on columns too slow - how can I get better performance?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, split

I've a dataset (around 10Gb) of call records. There's column with ip addresses that I want to split into four new columns. I'm trying to use:

```
df['ip'].fillna('0.0.0.0', inplace=True)
df = df.join(df['ip'].apply(lambda x: Series(x.split('.'))))
```

but it's tooooo slow... the `fillna` is fast, like 10s, but then it stays in the split for like 5 hours...

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: How did you load the data?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**This answer is outdated, as is this question.  The problem identified below [was fixed some time ago](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10081).  The pandas `str.split` method should now be fast.**

<s>It turns out that the `str.split` in Pandas (in `core/strings.py` as `str_split`) is actually very slow; it isn't any more efficient, and still iterates through using Python, offering no speedup whatsoever.</s>

Actually, see below. Pandas performance on this is simply miserable; it's not just Python vs C iteration, as doing the same thing with Python lists is the fastest method!

Interestingly, though, there's a trick solution that's much faster: writing the Series out to text, and then reading it in again, with '.' as the separator:

```
df[['ip0', 'ip1', 'ip2', 'ip3']] = \
    pd.read_table(StringIO(df['ip'].to_csv(None,index=None)),sep='.')
```

To compare, I use Marius' code and generate 20,000 ips:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO

def make_ip():
    return '.'.join(str(random.randint(0, 255)) for n in range(4))

df = pd.DataFrame({'ip': [make_ip() for i in range(20000)]})

%timeit df[['ip0', 'ip1', 'ip2', 'ip3']] = df.ip.str.split('.', return_type='frame')
# 1 loops, best of 3: 3.06 s per loop

%timeit df[['ip0', 'ip1', 'ip2', 'ip3']] = df['ip'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split('.')))
# 1 loops, best of 3: 3.1 s per loop

%timeit df[['ip0', 'ip1', 'ip2', 'ip3']] = \
    pd.read_table(StringIO(df['ip'].to_csv(None,index=None)),sep='.',header=None)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 46.4 ms per loop
```

---

Ok, so I wanted to compare all of this to just using a Python list and the Python split, which should be slower than using the more efficient Pandas:

```
iplist = list(df['ip'])
%timeit [ x.split('.') for x in iplist ]
100 loops, best of 3: 10 ms per loop
```

What!? Apparently, the best way to do a simple string operation on a large number of strings is to *throw out Pandas entirely*. **Using Pandas makes the process 400 times slower.** If you want to use Pandas, though, you may as well just convert to a Python list and back:

```
%timeit df[['ip0', 'ip1', 'ip2', 'ip3']] = \
    pd.DataFrame([ x.split('.') for x in list(df['ip']) ])
# 100 loops, best of 3: 18.4 ms per loop
```

There's something *very* wrong here.

Comment: Actually, it can go even faster; I'm messing with a version that's around 2-3 times faster. This makes Pandas string performance look *miserable*.

Comment: Well, we'll just need a PR to fix that! https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10081 (keep in mind, you DO need to handle NA's; which read_csv does handle)

Comment: @cge you need to pass ``header=None`` FYI

Comment: thank you very much. I guess maybe because dataframe is not continuous in memory so a lot time cost in lookup memory address

Comment: No, the problem has been figured out over on that github link, and should be fixed. It's not anything fundamental to dataframes; it's just a simple issue with the code for str_split.

Answer (score 1):

Example data (your questions are more likely to be answered if you provide this):

```
import pandas as pd
import random

def make_ip():
    return '.'.join(str(random.randint(0, 255)) for n in range(4))

df = pd.DataFrame({'ip': [make_ip() for i in range(20)]})

df
Out[4]: 
                 ip
0     153.1.219.147
1   110.170.184.123
2     91.100.92.150
3      61.148.99.64
4      94.175.253.3
5     30.29.220.218
6     7.118.167.173
7       71.99.78.94
8   240.122.200.194
9       48.16.177.0
10    81.155.96.173
11     202.91.134.9
12   90.155.159.176
13     169.74.28.73
14   149.133.115.45
15   168.196.41.132
16   145.195.15.234
17     12.200.28.27
18    146.255.29.80
19   228.226.143.45
```

Use pandas' builtin str methods for efficient string operations, and add them on directly to avoid a slow join:

```
df[['ip0', 'ip1', 'ip2', 'ip3']] = df.ip.str.split('.', return_type='frame')

df
Out[8]: 
                 ip  ip0  ip1  ip2  ip3
0     153.1.219.147  153    1  219  147
1   110.170.184.123  110  170  184  123
2     91.100.92.150   91  100   92  150
3      61.148.99.64   61  148   99   64
4      94.175.253.3   94  175  253    3
5     30.29.220.218   30   29  220  218
6     7.118.167.173    7  118  167  173
7       71.99.78.94   71   99   78   94
8   240.122.200.194  240  122  200  194
9       48.16.177.0   48   16  177    0
10    81.155.96.173   81  155   96  173
11     202.91.134.9  202   91  134    9
12   90.155.159.176   90  155  159  176
13     169.74.28.73  169   74   28   73
14   149.133.115.45  149  133  115   45
15   168.196.41.132  168  196   41  132
16   145.195.15.234  145  195   15  234
17     12.200.28.27   12  200   28   27
18    146.255.29.80  146  255   29   80
19   228.226.143.45  228  226  143   45
```

Comment: maybe show a timeit for apply vs using the str ops :)

Comment: This does not actually appear to be any faster.

Comment: --- processIP 5.261000156403 seconds --- (the method I post) , and yours --- processIP 5.238000154495 seconds ---, in a short dataset ...

Comment: @cge, wow, I was under the impression that the `.str` methods were supposed to be optimized, so looked at the question, could immediately see the canonical `pandas` API way to do it, and posted it. Looks like a fix is well underway though.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it was a simple bug in str.split that had unfortunate performance consequences. Your answer should be the best one in the near future!